# Using result of inner join on another query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables: `quotes`, `quote_items` and `products`.
`quotes` has a `created_by` field which corresponds to a `quote_id` field in `quote_items`.
`quote_items` also has a field `new_product_id` which corresponds to the `id` field in `products`.
`products` also has a `price` field.

I am trying to run a query that gets the `Total quoted value` for a specific `created_by` value.
What I have so far is:

```
SELECT `quote_items`.`new_product_id` FROM `quotes`
INNER JOIN `quote_items`
ON `quotes`.`id` = `quote_items`.`quote_id` Where `quotes`.`created_by` = 5
```

This returns all the product ids of all the quotes created by someone with an id of 5.
How do I run the last part of the query on this result, ie. get the prices relating to each product id and sum them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  SUM( p.price ) Total_quoted_value
FROM `quotes`
INNER JOIN `quote_items`
ON `quotes`.`id` = `quote_items`.`quote_id` 
INNER JOIN products p 
ON p.id = new_product_id
Where `quotes`.`created_by` = 5
```

----- EDIT ----------
An example how to calculate an average price

```
SELECT  SUM( p.price ) Total_quoted_value, AVG( p.price ) Avg_value
FROM `quotes`
INNER JOIN `quote_items`
ON `quotes`.`id` = `quote_items`.`quote_id` 
INNER JOIN products p 
ON p.id = new_product_id
Where `quotes`.`created_by` = 5;
```

A link to [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6655be/2)

------ EDIT -- a short explanation what the second join is doing --------------

We have three tables:

```
> select * from products
+ ------- + ----------------- + ---------- +
| id      | product_name      | price      |
+ ------- + ----------------- + ---------- +
| 1       | product 1         | 20         |
| 2       | product 2         | 40         |
| 3       | product 3         | 30         |
| 4       | product 4         | 15         |
| 5       | product 5         | 5          |
+ ------- + ----------------- + ---------- +
```

```
> select * from quotes
+ ------- + --------------- +
| id      | created_by      |
+ ------- + --------------- +
| 1       | 5               |
| 2       | 4               |
| 3       | 5               |
| 4       | 1               |
+ ------- + --------------- +
```

```
> select * from quote_items
+ ------------- + ------------------- +
| quote_id      | new_product_id      |
+ ------------- + ------------------- +
| 1             | 1                   |
| 1             | 2                   |
| 1             | 4                   |
| 2             | 2                   |
| 2             | 3                   |
| 2             | 5                   |
| 3             | 1                   |
| 3             | 3                   |
| 4             | 2                   |
| 4             | 4                   |
| 4             | 5                   |
+ ------------- + ------------------- +
```

The first join:

```
SELECT  *
FROM `quotes`
INNER JOIN `quote_items`
ON `quotes`.`id` = `quote_items`.`quote_id` ;

+ ------- + --------------- + ------------- + ------------------- +
| id      | created_by      | quote_id      | new_product_id      |
+ ------- + --------------- + ------------- + ------------------- +
| 1       | 5               | 1             | 1                   |
| 1       | 5               | 1             | 2                   |
| 1       | 5               | 1             | 4                   |
| 2       | 4               | 2             | 2                   |
| 2       | 4               | 2             | 3                   |
| 2       | 4               | 2             | 5                   |
| 3       | 5               | 3             | 1                   |
| 3       | 5               | 3             | 3                   |
| 4       | 1               | 4             | 2                   |
| 4       | 1               | 4             | 4                   |
| 4       | 1               | 4             | 5                   |
+ ------- + --------------- + ------------- + ------------------- +
```

I am assuming that you know how a simple join works, and an explanation is not needed here.
If not, then you can find a great explanation here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp
We are primarily interested in the second (combined) join and how it works. Here is our query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM quotes
INNER JOIN quote_items
ON quotes.id = quote_items.quote_id 
INNER JOIN products p 
ON p.id = new_product_id
```

Basically this query is equivalent to a simple, single join:

```
SELECT *
FROM <<ResultSet_of_the_first_join>>
INNER JOIN products p 
ON p.id = new_product_id
```

where < < ResultSet_of_the_first_join > > is a resultset (a set of rows returned by the first join - a kind of a virtual table in memory).
This join (the second one) produces the following resultset:

```
+ ---- + ------------+ ----------+ --------------- + ----+ ------------- + ------ +
| id   | created_by  | quote_id  | new_product_id  | id  | product_name  | price  |
+ ---- + ------------+ ----------+ --------------- + ----+ ------------- + ------ +
| 1    | 5           | 1         | 1               | 1   | product 1     | 20     |
| 1    | 5           | 1         | 2               | 2   | product 2     | 40     |
| 1    | 5           | 1         | 4               | 4   | product 4     | 15     |
| 2    | 4           | 2         | 2               | 2   | product 2     | 40     |
| 2    | 4           | 2         | 3               | 3   | product 3     | 30     |
| 2    | 4           | 2         | 5               | 5   | product 5     | 5      |
| 3    | 5           | 3         | 1               | 1   | product 1     | 20     |
| 3    | 5           | 3         | 3               | 3   | product 3     | 30     |
| 4    | 1           | 4         | 2               | 2   | product 2     | 40     |
| 4    | 1           | 4         | 4               | 4   | product 4     | 15     |
| 4    | 1           | 4         | 5               | 5   | product 5     | 5      |
+ ---- + ----------- + --------- + --------------- + ----+ ------------- + ------ +
```

Next, the WHERE clasue is applied to the returned resultset to select only rows that meet  WHERE conditions:

```
Where quotes.created_by = 5;
```

after this we get the following:

```
+ ---- + ------------+ ----------+ --------------- + ----+ ------------- + ------ +
| id   | created_by  | quote_id  | new_product_id  | id  | product_name  | price  |
+ ---- + ------------+ ----------+ --------------- + ----+ ------------- + ------ +
| 1    | 5           | 1         | 1               | 1   | product 1     | 20     |
| 1    | 5           | 1         | 2               | 2   | product 2     | 40     |
| 1    | 5           | 1         | 4               | 4   | product 4     | 15     |
| 3    | 5           | 3         | 1               | 1   | product 1     | 20     |
| 3    | 5           | 3         | 3               | 3   | product 3     | 30     |
+ ---- + ----------- + --------- + --------------- + ----+ ------------- + ------ +
```

and finally the query calcuates a sum and an average value from the `price` column:

```
SELECT  SUM( p.price ) Total_quoted_value, AVG( p.price ) Avg_value

+ ----------------------- + -------------- +
| Total_quoted_value      | Avg_value      |
+ ----------------------- + -------------- +
| 125                     | 25.0000        |
+ ----------------------- + -------------- +
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks. I'm just a bit confused with whats actually happening now. Could you break down what's actually happening please

Comment: out of interest, would there by some way to find the average quoted value in the same quote, instead of taking this result and dividing it by:Select COUNT('created_by') from `quotes`Where `quotes`.`created_by` = 5

Comment: @mrcurious I have appended an example how to calculate an average price. I'am not quite sure what do you mean by `average quoted value`, so I attached a link to a small demo with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6655be/2, if this query doesn't fit your needs, please look at this demo and show (in your question - by editing it) what values from this sample data the query is excpeted to return.

Comment: perfect, thanks for your help! Just with regards to the Inner joins, i'm still a bit confused as to what the second inner join is doing. Thanks again

Comment: @mrcurious i've appended an explanation how the second join works, regards.